# Android public.xml: determining the default values for resource IDs

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to understand how I can determine the default values of attributes defined in public.xml. For instance, I'd like to know what the default value of textColorPrimary is. Pawing through the system xml files yields:

```
•   attrs.xml:  <attr name="textColorPrimary" format="reference|color" />
•   themes.xml:     <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_dark</item>
•   public.xml: <public type="attr" name="textColorPrimary" id="0x01010036" />
```

When a search around for primary_text_dark, all I get is this.

```
•   public.xml:  <public type="color" name="primary_text_dark"
id="0x01060001" />
```

So my question is, "What does 0x01060001 reference?". I.e., What is the darn default color :-)???

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: "For instance, I'd like to know what the default value of textColorPrimary is" -- that would depend upon your theme.

Comment: Sure, but I still don't see where the actual value is defined. Let's say that you are simply using the default them, "Theme". What is the value of textColorPrimary if that is your theme?